# Running commands on all/specific chef nodes in parallel

Tags: chef-infra, configuration-management

My development ,staging and production servers (webapps, webservers, databases and some other services) are provisioned and configured with chef infra and connected to chef-server.
I want to ssh and execute script on specific machines in parallel. general usecase for this problem: It can be refreshing settings on some service in some node group ( running `sudo chef-client` on all databases) or updating some new package on some nodes.

**For example**: I need to start nodejs/python servers on all web server nodes:

```
Servers-List:
  - web-server-a1
  - web-server-a2
  - web-server-a3
  - db-mongo
  - db-cassandra
  - db-mysql
```

**Expected Result** would be: perform `npm start` command  on these servers only ,

```
- web-server-a1
- web-server-a2
- web-server-a3
```

What would be the best way doing it on chef?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [knife ssh](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_ssh/) command, which allows us to send commands to nodes in parallel. The nodes can be matched by wildcard names, roles, etc.

Example if you want to run `npm start` on the 3 web nodes:

```
knife ssh 'name:web-*' 'npm start'
```

Other options such as `-x <SSH username>`, `-i <SSH identity file>` (recommended) can be passed as required.

To run `chef-client` on all database nodes:

```
knife ssh 'name:db-*' 'sudo chef-client'
```

Run `uptime` on all nodes:

```
knife ssh 'name:*' 'uptime'
```